# How to call a WCF service from client script using ajax?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

My service contract, named IService1, is as follows

```
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;

    namespace WcfServiceDemo
    {
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            string GetData(int Value);
        }
    }
```

Here's my service implementation,

```
    using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

    namespace WcfServiceDemo
    {
        [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
        public class Service1 : IService1
        {
            public string GetData(int Value)
            {
                return string.Format("You entered: {0}", Value);
            }

        }
    }
```

My web.config,

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>

        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name ="ServiceBehavior">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="EndPointBehavior">
              <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

        <services>
          <service name ="WcfDemoService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService1" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" />
          </service>
        </services>

      </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
          -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Script for consuming WCF service,

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Client.aspx.cs"       Inherits="WcfServiceDemo.Client" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Enter a number:<input type="text" id="txtNum"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="AlertEnteredNum();"/>
        </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function AlertEnteredNum() {
                var Value = $('#txtNum').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Service1.svc/GetData',
                    data: '{"Value": "' + Value + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success: " + data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("error: " + result);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Always error callback gets executed. Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

I think I need to host on IIS, as I am setting compatibility mode in my config. But,
When I host this service on IIS, I am getting parser error as "Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."

And , if I remove this"targetFramework = 4" attribute, I am getting an exception as "Could not load file or assembly 'WcfServiceDemo' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

Comment: try with data: {Value:$('#txtNum').val()}

Comment: Tried, it's not working. There is some other issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got my mistake & it's solution.

Just needed to change the service element in config as:

```
<services>
  <service name ="WcfServiceDemo.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceDemo.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="EndPointBehavior" />
  </service>
</services>
```

where name ="WcfServiceDemo.Service1" is in format "namespace.ServiceImplementationName" & contract="WcfServiceDemo.IService1" is in format "namespace.ServiceContractName"

Answer (score 1):

For TargetFramework issue.
You shall check that your application pool is .net4.0 and not .net2.0

The javascript seems to be correct

Comment: yes my application pool was ".net2.0". But after changing it to ".net4.0", I am getting different parser error as " The value for the targetFramework attribute is invalid: '4'. Error: FrameworkName cannot have less than two components or more than three components.
Parameter name: frameworkName."

Comment: yes,
it's 4.0 only like
    <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
but I don't understand, why I am getting such error message